# nginx proxy + apache in docker

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, apache2

I am new in Docker.
And i had a task - create docker container with nginx that will be send php (dynamics) to the apache docker container.

I solved my problem. But i've spend much time. So i hope this will help to other people

There is many articles - how to build nginx + apache...
But they dont work in Docker

My problem was solved by changing nginx configuration file (my.conf | default ...)

**from:**

```
upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

**to:**

```
upstream backend {
    server apache2php:8080;
}
```

where apache2php is the service name in docker-compose.yml

**like this:**

```
version: "3"
services:

    apache2php:
        image: apache2php
        ports:
        - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
        - "/var/www/html:/var/www/html"

    mynginx:
        image: mynginx
        ports:
        - "80:80"
        volumes:
        - "/var/www/html:/var/www/html"
```

When i checked logs (/var/log/nginx/error.log) in the nginx container with my bad settings i found an error 111 (Connection refused while connecting to upstream)

And also there was not my local ip (127.0.0.1) in the Host field but another (like 10.5.100.2 - maybe another)

I think that docker use its own ip addresses in the docker's network and that IP-addresses are used by docker containers (nginx use 10.5.100.2:8080 when need to redirect php file to apache)

But when we go to 127.0.0.1:80 in outer network (like when we type the IP in the browser) Docker translate inner IP (nginx - 10.5.100.2:80) into outer IP that we type later (127.0.0.1:80)

Am i right?